# Logic App Execute Query and based on SP result set and assign

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-data-explorer

I am writing a logic app to to execute SP and return result and based on the result i am builing the Kusto Query till here it's working

after this step i am generating CSV table out of the result set and in that one of the column should be from kusto query how to return result from executed query result to csv column value ?

any thoughts on this ? one more complication is [image]
when i execute kusto query it's a forloop so i wont be able to get one item a time any suggestion on how to resolve this

Comment: have you considered, instead of running a query and using an additional step to try and persist its results to a CSV file, to run an .`export` command that does that for you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/data-export/export-data-to-storage

Comment: The result set is from different SP and I am running another sp to get data , Only thing i need now is how to get the result from Kusto query thats executed in logic app i am not seeing properties in dynamic object

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have fixed it using returning as Parse Json and using it from it

Comment: you can run Kusto Control command and write data to SQL and process the data, this will be the best way